# How to calculate weighted average of all other products in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe as below

```
category    sub category    price     revenue
A             A1              100     1000
A             A2              110     990
A             A3              120     890
B             B1              90      1200
B             B2              100     1100
B             B3              95      1050
```

I need to create a new column which is the weighted avg price(weighted with revenue within a category) for all subcategories(within a category) except the one in subcategory column,i.e for the 1st row, I need the weighted avg price of A2 & A3 only since A1 is the value in sub-category column. Can someone pls help?

Comment: How looks expected ouput?

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the weighted mean manually, while subtracting the self values:

```
tmp = (df.set_index(['category', 'sub category'])
         .eval('prod=price*revenue')
       )

g = tmp.groupby(level=0)

out = (g['prod'].transform('sum')
       .sub(tmp['prod'])
       .div(g['revenue'].transform('sum').sub(tmp['revenue']))
       )
```

Output:

```
category  sub category
A         A1              114.734043
          A2              109.417989
          A3              104.974874
B         B1               97.558140
          B2               92.333333
          B3               94.782609
dtype: float64
```